# Proof of equality of OLS projection matrix and GLS projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, projection-matrices

I'm struggling with the proof of the following proposition:

Given a $n\times n$ symmetric, positive-semidefinite matrix $\Omega$, a $n\times k$ matrix $X$ such that $rank(X)=k$, and an invertible matrix $Q$ such that:
$$\Omega X=XQ$$

Prove the following:
${{(X'{{\Omega }^{-1}}X)}^{-1}}X'{{\Omega }^{-1}}={{(X'X)}^{-1}}X'$

Here's my work before getting stuck:

[image]

I also tried playing with the Cholesky factorization of $\Omega$ but always ended up getting stuck with an irreducible expression. What am I missing? (for context, this problem is from  a graduate-level econometrics course)